# Jenkins job should be triggered "only" by another job in Multijob?

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, jenkins-plugins

I have a Multijob, which has three jobs P1, P2 and P3 and they are executed sequentially. But these jobs are also able to be built as independent jobs. Which mean P1, P2 and P3 can be built separately. But I do not want the jobs to be executed individually with "Build Now" option. Is there a way that we can bind the jobs only to Multijobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [matrix based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) to remove the job / build permission on those three jobs, or maybe restrict it to admin users.